# Why does the BeforeAllCallback not have a ParameterResolvers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-restdocs

In my test class I can use `@BeforeAll` to annotate a setup method e.g.

```
@BeforeAll
public void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)).build();
}
```

I want to do the same thing in an extension with the `BeforeAllCallback` e.g.

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
     // same as above, but I can not have RestDocumentationContextProvider in the signature or WebApplicationContext 
    }
}
```

In the extension `beforeAll` there is no support for `ParameterResolvers` which means I can not use the signature `ExtensionContext context, RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation`.

What is the difference between the annotation and the callback method? How can I get an instance of `RestDocumentationContextProvider` in my extensions beforeAll method?